# Cisco IOS built-in SSH client default version

Tags: switch, router, cisco-ios, ssh

You issue the command `ssh 192.168.97.97` from a IOS device and the destination IOS router/switch SSH server is accepting both SSH versions. Being that you did not specify a version to use on the SSH client, which version of SSH will be used to connect to the IOS SSH server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ssh version 2](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk583/tk617/technologies_tech_note09186a00800949e2.shtml) for IOS 12.1(19)E and later

SSH from one switch to another... for reasons I can't explain, Cisco calls SSHv2 SSH-1.99...

```
SRV1#debug ip ssh client
SSH Client debugging is on
SRV1#ssh 10.19.1.2

Password:
Jun  4 13:45:28.747 CDT: SSH1: sent protocol version id SSH-1.99-Cisco-1.25   <-----
Jun  4 13:45:28.787 CDT: SSH CLIENT0: protocol version id is - SSH-1.99-Cisco-1.25
Jun  4 13:45:28.787 CDT: SSH CLIENT0: sent protocol version id SSH-1.99-Cisco-1.25
```

Also from linux when connecting to IOS...

```
[mpenning@something ~]$ ssh -v dst1
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to dst1 [10.19.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mpenning/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mpenning/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/mpenning/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version Cisco-1.25     <-------
debug1: no match: Cisco-1.25
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0                         <--------
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

Comment: It's not clear that this answer addresses the IOS *client* default, since you demonstrate a non-IOS client.

Comment: Well-behaved SSH clients should use v2 by default and then fallback to v1 if v2 isn't available from the server or the client. I suppose it's a safe assumption that if you're initiating sessions from any device running 12.1(19)E and newer, to any device running 12.1(19)E and newer, SSHv2 should be used.

Comment: You can also force ssh with 'ip ssh version 2'. Then if OpenSSH client tries to connect (ssh -1 IOS_node) to it on sshv1 it'll get complaint 'Protocol major versions differ: 1 vs. 2' and will exit with return value 255

Comment: FYI - version 1.99 is defined in [RFC4253](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253). It's just a flag that signals compatibility with old SSH protocol versions.